# ObjectListView DataTreeListView context menu not showing

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have a problem showing a context menu on a treeviewlist item on right click.
The context is only showing when the FullRowSelect == false; 
Nothing happens when I set this to true **BUT** the cell right click event is fired.
The context menu strip property on the DataTreeListView is linked to 'cmenuOpdrachten'
The code i use:

```
  private void grdOrders_CellRightClick(object sender, CellRightClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.cmenuOpdrachten.Show(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);
    }
```

What is it that I do wrong?

Comment: Solved my problem by removing the opening event of the context menu

Comment: removed this
        private void cmenuOpdrachten_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (SelectedOrder != null)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Program.Log("GUI : Error order grid menu", Program.LogType.error);
            }
        }